# Kotlin serialization module. How to serialize/deserialize a plain json field?

Tags: json, kotlin

I have an object with the following structure:

```
enum class GeometryType { ... }

data class GeometryItem(
    val type: GeometryType,
    val geomtryJson: String
)
```

Where an example json could be:

```
{
    type: "Point",
    geometryJson: [12.0, 11.0]
}
```

So gemetryJson is a valid json string, but not quoted.

Could this be accomplished using Kotlin Serialization module?

Comment: `[12.0, 11.0]` is an array of number values. So in order to read it to `geomtryJson` you need to change this type from `String` to some collection type.

Comment: I don't need a collection, cause I need to convert this to JSON again. Cause I need to pass it to a 3d party library, which accepts JSON string. And this is not only array, this could be any valid json string.

Answer (score 0):

According to [JSON RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159):

> A JSON value MUST be an object, array, number, or string, or one of
> the following three literal names: false null true.

> The representation of strings is similar to conventions used in the C
> family of programming languages.  A string begins and ends with
> quotation marks.

> An array structure is represented as square brackets surrounding
> zero    or more values (or elements).  Elements are separated by
> commas.

So the value of `geometryJson: [12.0, 11.0]` has array type, not a string type.

As for `kotlinx-serialization` out of the box it won't handle such deserialization. You can try to write your own [decoder](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/formats.md#custom-formats-experimental), but I would suggest to use Jackson library for this task. Not a full solution:

```
val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper()
mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true)
val json ="""
    {
        type: "POINT",
        geometryJson: "[12.0, 11.0]"
    }
""".trimIndent()

    val geometryItem = mapper.readValue<GeometryItem>(json)
    println("geometryItem = $geometryItem")
```

With such config you can handle at least unquoted json fields.
As for reading array values I would suggest to read it to array of doubles, and if you need to represent it as string use such conversion:

```
val stringArray = doubleArray.map { it.toString() }.toTypedArray().contentToString()
```